# Google Chrome Frame not working

Tags: google-chrome-frame

My site is set to prompt for installation of the Google Chrome Frame for IE8 and below.

On one of the machine that runs Windows Server 2003 R2, 64bit with IE8, I got a message in the Google Chrome Frame install overlay "We are sorry. Google Chrome Frame is only available for Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and 9 on Windows 7 / Vista / XP SP2 or greater".

Does it mean that Chrome Frame cannot recognize IE8 on a Win 2003 Server box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Google Chrome Frame does not work right in IE that runs on Windows Server 2003 64bit

Answer (score 0):

According to [Chrome Frame Plugin's FAQ](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161796):

You'll need the following system requirements to use Google Chrome Frame:

- Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8
- 32- and 64-bit Windows XP, Window Vista,
- Windows 7, Windows 8 Minimum 512 MB of RAM (recommended)
- Administrative rights